# store paragraph of text in sqlite

Tags: database, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite

i am new to ios development.actually i am working on an app which just simply display 
a text in paragraphs..i need to know how to add texts in paragraph in sqlite & fetch it back again from DB & show it to the user.

thanks in advance ..

Comment: If you are asking about iphone sdk, this is probably a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311411/how-to-store-text-as-paragraphs-in-sqlite-database-in-iphone-app

Comment: Also, you should include more about what you tried, where you looked first, some kind of code snippet, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In general you use sqlite like any other DB - as long as you have a provider for it. I don't know the iphone environment provider for sqlite, but it should be compatile with regular providers.

(use TEXT to store the paragraph...)